# add view dynamically in a fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I need to show some information in an agenda style, so i'm using fragment to show the information in the different days. Every day have some column to showing the room.

I create the structure but i have some problem when i try to put inside the information

**agenda_child_tv - textview where i put the peace of information**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text_child"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:padding="3sp"/>
```

**agenda_child_ll - the colum**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/agenda_aula_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/agenda_aula_title" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout  
        android:id="@+id/agenda_aula_esp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**agenda_day**

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/horizontal_fragment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="@dimen/agenda_tv_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="#BDBDBD" >

                <TextView 
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/agenda_tv_width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/agenda_tv_height"
                    android:text="9.00"
                    android:padding="@dimen/agenda_tv_padding"
                    android:textColor="@color/agenda_orario_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/agenda_tv_textsize" />

                <!-- A lot of textview for the hours -->

            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Here i put, dinamically, the colum for the room in each day --> 

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

**Agenda**

The code below is not very dynamically but i wrote a simplified versione to show you my problem

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.agenda_day, container, false);

    LinearLayout dayLL = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.horizontal_fragment);

    //Retriving LL agenda_child_ll
        LinearLayout aula = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.agenda_child_ll, container, false);

        //Setting the classroom name
        TextView aulaName = (TextView) aula.findViewById(R.id.agenda_aula_title);
        aulaName.setText("room A");

        //Retriving LL agenda_aula_esp
        LinearLayout roomLL = (LinearLayout) aula.findViewById(R.id.agenda_aula_esp);

        //Retriving TV child
        TextView child = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.agenda_child_tv, container, false);
        child.setText("test");

        //Adding child to the room
        roomLL.addView(child);

        //adding room to the day
        dayLL.addView(aula);

        //Creating the column for the classroom "room B"

        LinearLayout aula2 = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.agenda_child_ll, container, false);

        TextView aulaName2 = (TextView) aula2.findViewById(R.id.agenda_aula_title);
        aulaName2.setText("room B");

        dayLL.addView(aula2);
}
```

This is the result. The textview child wasn't added to the layout.
Can someone help me? :)

[image of the result](http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/2566/avdm.png)

Comment: I kinda feel like you should be trying to use gridview with an adapter instead of what you're doing. Adapters are meant to work very efficiently with dynamic data

Comment: Thanks. But i think that with the gridwith you can scroll only vertical or horizontal, not both...

I solved the problem, i changed layout_height in agenda_aula_title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, i changed layout_height in agenda_aula_title.

The textview i added was displayed out of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar problem and solved it the same way. My app has a main activity and two fragments. First fragment is a List Fragment which shows a list of formula. On clicking any formula a FormulaExpressionFragment, showing expressions for the formula, replaces the FormulaTitlesFragment. I wanted to dynamically add layout containing a calculator for the formula expression in the FormulaExpressionFragment. This is how I achieved it.

```
public class FormulaExpressionsFragment extends Fragment {

private TextView mTextView;
private TextView mFormulaTitle;
LinearLayout formulaExpressionsLayout;
View rootView;
View formulaCalculator;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_formula_expressions, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
void displayFormulaExpression(int position){
    mTextView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.formula_expression_view);
    mFormulaTitle = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.formula_title_view);
    mTextView.setText(getResources().getTextArray(R.array.formula_expressions)[position]);
    mFormulaTitle.setText(getResources().getTextArray(R.array.formula_titles)[position]);
    mFormulaTitle.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));
}

void displayFormulaCalculator(int position){
    formulaExpressionsLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.formula_expression_layout);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    formulaCalculator = inflater.inflate(R.layout.formula_1, formulaExpressionsLayout, false);
    formulaExpressionsLayout.addView(formulaCalculator);
```

fragment_formula_expressions.xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/formula_expression_layout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/formula_title_view"
    android:text="Formula Title"
    android:padding="5dp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/formula_expression_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Formula Expression"
    android:padding="5dp" />
```

formula_1.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/formula_calculator">
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/mud_density"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=" × 0.052 × "/>
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/tvd"/>
```

Pay special attention to

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

they should be set to "wrap_content" otherwise the view added below them will not show up in the layout as the top view will take all the display height.