# How to dynamically add a TableRow in a Fragment?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments

I am new in Android programming, currently I am trying to insert a textview inside the table layout dynamically in fragment. It worked while extending the class to Activity. Below is my code snippet. Am I missing something?

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_schedule, null);
    TableLayout ll = (TableLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
    TableRow tr= new TableRow(getActivity());
    TextView tv1 = new TextView(getActivity());
    tv1.setText("TEST NUMBER");
    tv1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    tv1.setTextSize(20);
    tv1.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    tr.addView(tv1);
    ll.addView(tr);
    return view;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you facing any issues with the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to give view.findViewById,
because you are adding that in the view.

```
TableLayout ll = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
```

Check [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15243782/add-view-dynamically-in-a-fragment) it will surely help you.

Answer (score 2):

- **What you have in your code** ::You have background and the text color same so you are not able to view the text
- **Solution**:: Change Either the textcolor or the background

***I have tested as below***

---

**activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</FrameLayout>
```

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/table"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</TableLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

package com.example.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Fragment newFragment = fragmentOne.newInstance();  
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();  
        ft.replace(R.id.container, newFragment).commit();  
    }   
}
```

**fragmentOne.java**

```
package com.example.test;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class fragmentOne extends Fragment{

    public static fragmentOne newInstance(){
        fragmentOne fragment = new fragmentOne();
        return  fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        TableLayout ll = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.table);
        TableRow tr= new TableRow(getActivity());
        TextView tv1 = new TextView(getActivity());
        tv1.setText("TEST NUMBER");
        tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        tv1.setTextSize(20);
        tv1.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        tr.addView(tv1);
        ll.addView(tr);
        return view;
    }

}
```

---

**Snapshot**::

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inf, ViewGroup container, Bundle state) {

    View view = inf.inflate(R.layout.records_fragment, container, false);

    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.records);

    // Do something with the table declare in fragment.
    return view;
}
```