# adding & removing rows to a TableLayout within a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablelayout

I'm having issues with adding/removing form elements based on the item selected.

Here is what's within my listener class for the rtSpinner element:

```
     selectedRamp = rtSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
     rampImage = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.rampImageView);
     dimTable = (TableLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.dimTable);

            switch (selectedRamp)

            {
                case 0: // one ramp, one crossing
                    rampImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.oneramponecross);
                    rampDimYY = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.rampDimYY);
                    rampDimZZ = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.rampDimZZ);
                    rowYY = (TableRow) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tableRowYY);
                    rowZZ = (TableRow) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tableRowZZ);
                    rowYY.addView(rampDimYY);
                    rowZZ.addView(rampDimZZ);
                    dimTable.addView(rowYY);
                    dimTable.addView(rowZZ);
                    break;
```

as you can see, dimTable is the TableLayout, and each dimension has its own TableRow that I'm trying to add once the specific item is selected. I'm getting errors when I open the specific fragment, here's the logcat:

```
09-08 09:40:53.107    2944-2944/com.josh.cs_4401app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.josh.cs_4401app, PID: 2944
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3562)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3415)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3360)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3336)
        at com.josh.cs_4401app.RampTypeChooserFragment$1.onItemSelected(RampTypeChooserFragment.java:92)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:893)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:48)
        at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:861)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I can see that there's an error with the addView at line 92 (dimTable.addView(rowYY);) but I'm not sure how to interpret/fix it.

I've referenced [add view dynamically in a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15243782/add-view-dynamically-in-a-fragment) and [How to dynamically add a TableRow in a Fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25346231/how-to-add-tablerow-in-fragment-dynamically) so far, but I feel like they may not be perfectly suited for fragment use.

Edit:

Okay I found my issue. I was trying to set the fields to pre-existing ones defined in the XML layout, but they have to be created within the fragment class instead. I removed the XML stuff and changed my class to this, and it worked:

```
selectedRamp = rtSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
            rampImage = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.rampImageView);
            dimTable = (TableLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.dimTable);

            switch (selectedRamp)

            {
                case 0: // one ramp, one crossing
                    rampImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.oneramponecross);
                    TextView rowYYview = new TextView(getActivity());
                    TextView rowZZview = new TextView(getActivity());
                    rowYYview.setText("YY: ");
                    rowZZview.setText("ZZ: ");
                    rowYYview.setTextSize(20);
                    rowZZview.setTextSize(20);
                    EditText rampDimYY = new EditText(getActivity());
                    EditText rampDimZZ =  new EditText(getActivity());
                    TableRow rowYY = new TableRow(getActivity());
                    TableRow rowZZ = new TableRow(getActivity());
                    rowYY.addView(rampDimYY);
                    rowYY.addView(rowYYview);
                    rowZZ.addView(rampDimZZ);
                    rowZZ.addView(rowZZview);
                    dimTable.addView(rowYY);
                    dimTable.addView(rowZZ);
                    break;
```

Comment: You're not creating any new Views, and you're using `findViewById()` to get references to them, so they already exist and have parents. Either instantiate new Views with `new`, or inflate an existing layout to add to your table.

Comment: @MikeM. yep, I realized it's hard to add stuff that's already supposed to be there.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I'm misreading your code. Are you trying to add new rows to the table, or move them there from somewhere else?